# Loading css into Next.js the right way

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I have read a few different sources about this and according to the [official docs](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/styling-components):

> Consequently, there are a bunch of practical issues to consider with
>   traditional CSS-file-based styling (especially with SSR), so we
>   suggest avoiding this method when styling for Next.js.
>
> Instead we recommend CSS in JS, which you can use to style individual
>   components rather than importing CSS files.
>
> Next.js comes preloaded with a CSS in JS framework called styled-jsx,
>   specifically designed to make your life easier. It allows you to write
>   familiar CSS rules for your components; rules will have no impact on
>   anything other than the components (not even child components).

But I have seen tutorials out there showing that you can load in css files like:

```
import Head from "next/head";
const Layout = props => (
  <>
    <Head>
      <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </Head>
    <Header />
    <main>{props.children}</main>
  </>
);
```

This would make my life much easier because I am using an html theme which I am porting to a next.js project. And the theme.css file is 23000 lines of code long. Imagine now I had to try and find all those css classes, extract them and put them into their individual components. That would take forever!

So, the actual question is, is it really that bad to just pull in the entire stylesheet and use it 'globally'?

Answer (score 0):

I am actually trying to figure out too the best way to load css in a next js project, I decided recently to import all my **pages** style sheets in the `_app.js` but then i found that my **lighthouse** score went from 70% to 42%. I used always the jsx approach and i guess it is much better for better performance.
like this for example :

```
const ReVerifyLink = () => (
  <div>
    <p>
      Click
      <Link href={{ pathname: routes.RE_VERIFY }}>
        <a>here</a>
      </Link>
      to re-verify your email.
    </p>
    <style jsx scoped>{`
      a {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #ed8f1f;
        margin: 0 5px;
      }
    `}</style>
  </div>
);
```